# Attach vs fetch on edit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Lets say I have `Product` model which looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And for instance user is allowed only to change `Price` field. So I have this viewmodel:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I receive this viewmodel in controller, is it ok to do something like this:

```
            var updatedProduct = new Product { ID = product.ID };
            db.Products.Attach(updatedProduct);

            updatedProduct.Price= product.Price;

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Or should I fetch it and then change it like this:

```
            var updatedProduct = dbo.Products.FindByID(product.ID);

            updatedProduct.Name = product.Name;
            updatedProduct.Description = product.Description;

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I see Microsoft uses the second approach when auto generating CRUD. But attach means one less db round trip. Is there any reason why I shoudn't use it?

Comment: Attach is when an item already exists on the DB not when you are adding a new item.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure about "FindByID", "Find" does make a roundtrip to db if that entity is not in the current context, unlike attach. But you are right the two snippets do exactly the same thing except the first one will not make a round trip to the store to fetch the entity. So I see no reason not to use the attach approch.